# Detect WebKit Version 525 and Below With RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, webkit, version, browser-detection

I'm no good at Regular Expressions, really!

I would like to specifically detect WebKit browsers below version 525.

I have a regular expression [`/WebKit/[\d.]+/.exec(navigator.appVersion)`] that correctly returns `WebKit/5….…`, really, I'd like it to return only the version number, but if the browser isn't WebKit, return `null`, or better still `0`.

For example, if the browser was Trident, Presto or Gecko, return `null`, whereas if the browser is WebKit, return it's version number.

To clarify, I would like the regular expression to check if `navigator.appVersion` contains `WebKit` and if it does not, return null, if it does, return the version number.

I appreciate all your help!

Please let's keep this focused, let's not flirt with jQuery or the sort, it's overkill in this scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm providing this with the usual caveats: you should use this only if you are absolutely sure there is no way to test the actual feature you want to use that differs between WebKit versions:

```
function checkWebKit() {
    var result = /AppleWebKit\/([\d.]+)/.exec(navigator.userAgent);
    if (result) {
        return parseFloat(result[1]);
    }
    return null;
}
```